Slack to Google Sheets integration "dispatch failed" error from slash command
I have created a simple slash command in Slack which retrieves some data from a google sheet.  The sheet extension is deployed as a web app and works fine, there is no code error.  However, after about a week, the slash command no longer works and returns a "dispatch failed" error.  To fix, I have to redeploy the web app (keeping the same URL). Again, it works fine for a week or so then fails with the same error. Is there a way that I can avoid having to do this and get the web app to work permanently?

Google sometimes regularly(about a week) revokes  granted authorization for webapps(probably as a security measure). To reduce automatic revokations, reduce the scopes used by the script:

Use @OnlyCurrentDoc, when only access to one document is needed

Set explicit scopes

Reduce the number of unverified apps in your account

Reduce the number of users accessing your webapp

Try changing to a new GCP and/or try configuring a Oauth consent screen with test users

if all else fails, you may need to verify your app with Google



Brilliant, thanks.  I will try these.  Your help is very much appreciated!
